# Plugin management with my custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm developing a wordpress plugin for a project. I'm expected to manage other plugins in this plugin. For example, I will be able to install Akismet over my plugin. I have done things like install, activating, deactivating. But I could not delete the plugin.

I can also delete direct attachment files, but I don't want to. I should use as many wordpress functions as possible.

```
delete_plugins('litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php')
```

This function does not work. I tried to integrate this function, but it was very complicated. Can you help me?

**--EDİT--**

I'm sorry, I didn't pay attention. There is another problem right now. I wrote a new plugin and it worked fine when I added the following code.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'index' );

function index() {
    delete_plugins( [
        'litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php',
    ] );
}
```

But it didn't work on my own plugin.

`add_action('exampleUninstallPlugin','exampleUninstallPlugin');
function exampleUninstallPlugin($plugins){
    delete_plugins($plugins);
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'customTestFunction' );
function customTestFunction() {
    register_rest_route( 'turhost/rest', '/api', array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'show_fields'
    ) );
}
function show_fields( $request ) {
        $parameters = json_decode( base64_decode( $request->get_param( 'data' ) ), true );
        if ( $parameters['action'] == "uninstallInstalledPlugin" ) {
            do_action('turhostUninstallPlugin',[
               'litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php'
            ]);
        }
}`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_plugins/#parameters). The parameter must be an array, not a single string. I'm not sure if this will resolve the issue as I haven't used this function before.

So your function call should be:

```
delete_plugins([
  'litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php',
]);
```

**-- Edit after question update: --**

In order to make `add_action('exampleUninstallPlugin','exampleUninstallPlugin');` work, you need to invoke that `exampleUninstallPlugin` action from some code via `do_action('exampleUninstallPlugin', $args)` like you did in your `show_fields` callback with `do_action('turhostUninstallPlugin')`.

Is your `show_fields` function invoked? If so, you need to correct the action name in the function or vice versa:

```
add_action('turhostUninstallPlugin', 'turhostUninstallPlugin');
function turhostUninstallPlugin($plugins) {
  delete_plugins($plugins);
}

function show_fields( $request ) {
  // …
  if ( $parameters['action'] == "uninstallInstalledPlugin" ) {
    do_action('turhostUninstallPlugin',[
      'litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php'
    ]);
  }
  // …
}
```

Comment: My message is long, I have edited the subject.

Comment: Please have a look again. You mismatched your action name.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping us, Fabian. I arranged it as you said. I'm always making a mistake because I have to hurry. I apologize again.
The following error is returned when I call the Rest service.
*There was an error parsing JSON data

Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

Comment: Did my answer helped with your issue or not? It's not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: Corrected function as you said. But he gave me the error I said above.

** error: There was an error parsing JSON data Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 **

Comment: It's still not clear to me… Did you check the response and stuff? Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Use TGM plugin activation, for requiring other plugins inside a plugin for your plugin to work.

Here you go http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: Thanks for help. But I can't use it because there are project requirements. I need to do this with wordpress plugins and functions.

Comment: Oh okay, I wish I could help but am not skilled enough as of yet to help right away. I am sure someone will help and your problem will be resolved.